# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an issue where I have an `interface` that describes some dynamic data where the values of each property can be one of many types, but I can't assign a variable that is one of those types.

Here's my `interface`:

```
interface MyDict {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

Here's some data of that type:

```
const data: MyDict = {
  hello: 'world',
  test: 123,
};
```

However when I try to pull values from `data` and assign it to a variable typed `string` or `number`, it fails.

```
const example: string = data.hello;
/* ->
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2322)
*/
```

`data.hello` is allowed to be either a `string` or a `number`, in this case it is a `string`, but when I try to assign it to variable `example` that can only be a `string` it unexpectedly fails. I'm under the impression that I can think of `|` as "or", but perhaps I'm wrong. Is there something I'm missing about union types? I'd really appreciate some pointers! :)

EDIT: I was able to get it to work by casting `data.hello` to a string, like so:

```
const example: string = data.hello as string;
```

Is this the right solution here, or is there a better practice for this use case?

Comment: Yes, you've stumbled upon the right solution. You know that the variable is a string, but the compiler only sees that its `string | number`. Compilers aren't magic, they're just very clever at certain things, and this level of flow analysis is not one of them.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to deal with this is to type check within your code.  For instance:

```
if (typeof data.hello === 'string') {
  const whatever: string = data.hello;
}
```

The compiler views `data.hello` as two possible types, so if you want to declare a variable with a single type, you have to exclude the other possibility first.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the info. How does this differ from casting the variable (`whatever` in your example)?

Comment: Casting would make compiler warnings go away, but it doesn't actually ensure the correct type at the time of execution.  In other words, it doesn't prevent errors when trying to run unsupported operations against the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be better:

```
const example: keyof MyDict = data.test;
```

Comment: I don't think this will fit my use-case, as the variable `example` must strictly be a string.